# escaping meta character using awk

Tags: shell, csv, awk

Is there better way to escape pipe(|) from the pipe separated file?

I have pipe separated file, I tried running the awk command, it is working fine only for the records who doesn't have escaped double quotes. because it is considering field separator as double quotes.

Input file:

```
"first | last | name" |" john | white "| age | 52
school |" ABC | USA "| year | 2016
Home | Road | year\" | 1989\" 
company |" Pvt | ltd "| joining | 2019
```

Code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }              
  { for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)      
        gsub(/\|/,"\\|",$i)    
    print
  }
' testfile.txt
```

Output I am getting:

```
"first \| last \| name" |" john \| white "| age | 52
school |" ABC \| USA "| year | 2016
Home | Road | year\" \| 1989\" 
company |" Pvt \| ltd "| joining | 2019
```

Expecting output :

```
"first \| last \| name" |" john \| white "| age | 52
school |" ABC \| USA "| year | 2016
Home | Road | year\" | 1989\" 
company |" Pvt \| ltd "| joining | 2019
```

In 3rd Row, it is escaping pipe after year, but it is wrong as that double quote is part of 3rd column.
Can I work on particular column to escape pipe if it belongs to same column

Comment: Could you please explain more on how you want to perform substitution part? Thank you.

Comment: `that double quote is part of 3rd column`: Can you tell what text should be in 3rd column?  Isn't 3rd column just `" ABC \| USA "` ?

Comment: Your input is CSV-like (just with `|` instead of `,` as the separator) but then it doesn't conform to any of the CSV "standards" in that it has `"`s in fields that aren't quoted, e.g. `year\"` instead of `"year"""`. Are you sure that's the format you're using as it would be a very odd choice to choose not to conform to any standard and so make things more difficult than necessary (as you apparently have discovered). Can't you just change to use a standard format like https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 (but keeping `|` instead of `,`)? If you did that then your awk script would work as-is.

Comment: @anubhava if you chck 3rd row, 3rd column should be year\" and 4th column is 1989\".. where as in 2nd row 3rd column is year. and second column is "ABC \| USA"

Comment: @EdMorton this is my input .. I don't have control on that file creation.. they are enclosing only | in double quotes, rest I need to handle

Comment: Can't you push back on that since they're presumably asking you to handle CSV input but then sending you something that's not CSV by any standard definition?

Comment: If you do manage to get real CSV input then see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for how it can be handled with awk. If you really want to try to take on the challenge in your question, though, then make sure to include a line like `this | "is\\" | tricky\\\"` in your sample input to make sure an escaped backslash before a closing `"` is handled correctly as, presumably, ```\\``` followed by `"` rather than ```\``` followed by `\"`, etc.. Good luck!

Comment: Also include `this | "is\" | also" | tricky` in your sample input (assuming that's how you'd include a quote plus a pipe symbol in a quoted string, to catch another edge case (I'm sure there's more....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your example set of input & output, following `awk` solution may work for you:

```bash
awk '{
   p = $0
   while (match(p, /(^|[^\\])"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"/)) {
      m = substr(p,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
      gsub(/\|/, "\\|", m)
      buf = buf substr(p,1,RSTART) m
      p = substr(p,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
   $0 = buf p
   buf = ""
} 1' file

"first \| last \| name" |" john \| white "| age | 52
school |" ABC \| USA "| year | 2016
Home | Road | year\" | 1989\"
company |" Pvt \| ltd "| joining | 2019
```

---

**Alternative one-liner solution using `perl`:**

```bash
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/$&=~s~\|~\\|~gr/ge' file

"first \| last \| name" |" john \| white "| age | 52
school |" ABC \| USA "| year | 2016
Home | Road | year\" | 1989\"
company |" Pvt \| ltd "| joining | 2019
```

[RegEx Demo of regex used above](https://regex101.com/r/sB5yQW/2)

Answer (score 2):

One common approach would see `\"` replaced with a nonsensical string, the normal operation performed, then the nonsensical string replaced with `\"`.  The nonsensical string will need to be something that does not show up in the original input and it cannot include characters that are treated specially by `awk` (eg, `&` when used in string replacement functions).

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
      { gsub(/\\"/,"@@%%",$0)             # replace \" with @@%% then continue with original code
        for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)
            gsub(/\|/,"\\|",$i)
        gsub(/@@%%/,"\\\"")               # replace @@%% with \"
        print
      }
' testfile.txt
```

This generates:

```
"first \| last \| name" |" john \| white "| age | 52
school |" ABC \| USA "| year | 2016
Home | Road | year\" | 1989\"
company |" Pvt \| ltd "| joining | 2019
```

**NOTES:** as mentioned in comments ...

- life would be much easier if the input used a common/standard format
- potential solutions get messier as the input formats get messier (eg, this answer will have issues properly processing something like `"is\\"`)

Comment: The value of `RS` is the common "nonsensical string" to use for things like this since it's guaranteed to not be present in RS-separated input and the default value of `\n` is easy to work with as it's just 1 char and so can be negated in a bracket expression if/when necessary.

Comment: @markp-fuso : if u wanna go the "non-sensical bytes" route, something like `\301\30\1` would be close to absolutely bullet proof, even for most binary files - just avoid `\0` or `\377` - those appear in large chunks in binary files all the time. if u don't wanna use `ASCII control` bytes, then maybe `\371\300` or even `\556\666\776` or `\531\642\753` - or just any combination that thoroughly violates `UTF-8` rules. `gawk` unicode mode is fine with those are long as you don't run it through `length()` function, or `match()` function with a regex of anything except `match( str, /$/)`)

Comment: ….. but `g/sub()/split()` functions are cool with these type of non-sensical seps. `ASCII` control bytes are still fully valid `UTF-8`, so i use that route only very occasionally. The `\ 3 [067] [0-7]` space has all 13 `UTF-8-invalid` bytes. for u to pick. ps :  `match( str, /$/ ) - 1` is a trick i found that could get `gawk` unicode mode to spit out the proper byte-count of ANY input, including full blown binary data, and not complain at all